# ESLint warnings and error with vue.js - vue/require-default-prop & vue/require-prop-type-constructor

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I am creating my first SPA using Vue.js, Babel and WebPack. A Vue component has the following script:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: String,
    required: true
  }
}
</script>
```

When I run eslint I get the following warnings and error:

```
8:5   warning  Prop 'name' requires default value to be set      vue/require-default-prop
9:5   warning  Prop 'required' requires default value to be set  vue/require-default-prop
9:15  error    The "required" property should be a constructor   vue/require-prop-type-constructor
```

I have copied the code from a tutorial I am following and I cannot understand how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

name should be an object,

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the issue and find the official document from
https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-default-prop.html
This rule requires default value to be set for each props that are not marked as required (except Boolean props).

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

------example from https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-default-prop.html

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    /* ✓ GOOD */
    a: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    b: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    c: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      required: false
    },
    d: {
      type: Boolean, // Boolean is the only type that doesn't require default
    },

    /* ✗ BAD */
    e: Number,
    f: [Number, String],
    g: [Boolean, Number],
    j: {
      type: Number
    },
    i: {
      type: Number,
      required: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```